# Twitter_Streaming_Data_Error

Tags: twitter, streaming, flume

I am getting the below error when I am trying to access the Twitter data through Streaming. I am not sure the root cause for it. I am using Filechannel to download the data from Twitter.

```
16/08/03 11:15:00 ERROR twitter.TwitterSource: Exception while streaming tweets
404:The URI requested is invalid or the resource requested, such as a user, does not exist.
Unknown URL. See Twitter Streaming API documentation at htp://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api
Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
    htp://www.google.co.jp/search?q=ec814753 or
    htp://www.google.co.jp/search?q=0a74cca1
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[ec814753-0a74cca1], statusCode=404, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, featureSpecificRateLimitStatus=null, version=2.2.6}
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:185)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:65)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.get(HttpClientWrapper.java:93)
    at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl.getSampleStream(TwitterStreamImpl.java:160)
    at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl$4.getStream(TwitterStreamImpl.java:149)
    at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl$4.getStream(TwitterStreamImpl.java:147)
    at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl$TwitterStreamConsumer.run(TwitterStreamImpl.java:426)
16/08/03 11:15:00 INFO twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl: Establishing connection.
16/08/03 11:15:01 INFO twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl: 404:The URI requested is invalid or the resource requested, such as a user, does not exist.
Unknown URL. See Twitter Streaming API documentation at htp://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api

16/08/03 11:15:01 INFO twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl: Waiting for 20000 milliseconds
16/08/03 11:15:21 ERROR twitter.TwitterSource: Exception while streaming tweets
404:The URI requested is invalid or the resource requested, such as a user, does not exist.
Unknown URL. See Twitter Streaming API documentation at htp://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api
Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
    htp://www.google.co.jp/search?q=ec814753 or
    htp://www.google.co.jp/search?q=0a74cca1
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[ec814753-0a74cca1], statusCode=404, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, featureSpecificRateLimitStatus=null, version=2.2.6}
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:185)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:65)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.get(HttpClientWrapper.java:93)
    at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl.getSampleStream(TwitterStreamImpl.java:160)
    at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl$4.getStream(TwitterStreamImpl.java:149)
    at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl$4.getStream(TwitterStreamImpl.java:147)
    at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl$TwitterStreamConsumer.run(TwitterStreamImpl.java:426)
16/08/03 11:15:21 INFO twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl: Establishing connection.
16/08/03 11:15:23 INFO twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl: 404:The URI requested is invalid or the resource requested, such as a user, does not exist.
Unknown URL. See Twitter Streaming API documentation at htp://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api

16/08/03 11:15:23 INFO twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl: Waiting for 40000 milliseconds
```

Comment: How are you streaming the tweets? using Flume! If yes can you share your flume.conf?

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify the below fieldsbefore starting flume

> TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = 
>   TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = 
>   TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken = 
>   TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret =

It is possible that the credentials are expired. Regenerate the access token and try again.